# how to print integer value retrieved from mongodb into jtable?

Tags: java, mongodb, swing, jframe, jtable

I am trying to print integer values (which are stored in MongoDB)into jtable.
here is one of the MongoDB entry:

```
Inserted Document: 108 
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5912effdf9c13f1ab9377eb6"
  },
  "SrNo": "53",
  "Brand": "Vivo",
  "Product Name": "Y51L",
  "Price": 10000,
  "Brand Reputation": 7,
  "Features": 10,
  "Rating": 4
}
```

I am able to print string values like productname, brand and srno.but I am unable to print integer values like ratings, features etc.

Here is the code:

```
    JTable table = new JTable();                                                                             
    String[] columns = new String[]{"SrNo","Brand","Product Name","Price"};

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns,0);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame2.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame2.setBounds(100, 100, 677, 392);                                                               
    frame2.setVisible(true);

    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);



    DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
                 //int i=1;
                 while (cursor.hasNext())
                 {
                     DBObject obj = cursor.next();
                     String SrNo = (String)obj.get("SrNo");
                     //ObjectId id = (ObjectId)obj.get("_id");
                     String Brand = (String)obj.get("Brand");
                     String ProductName = (String)obj.get("Product Name");

                    //String price = (String)obj.get("Price");
                     //String price = Integer.toString((String)obj.get("Price"));
                     //int BrandReputation = Integer.parseInt((String)obj.get("Brand Reputation"));
                     //String brandrep = String.valueOf(BrandReputation);
                     //int Features = Integer.parseInt((String)obj.get("Features"));

                     //int Ratings = Integer.parseInt((String)obj.get("Rating"));

                     model.addRow(new Object[]{SrNo,Brand,ProductName});


                 }
                 table.setModel(model);
                 cursor.close();
                 mongoClient.close();
```

Inside the while loop you can see the commented lines of codes those are all ways that I tried to print integer values but it all failed.Is there any other way to print integer values into jtable?

Comment: Is there any other way to print integer values into jtable? == `getColumnClass`, it would need to store correct data type in db side too (to avoids any `parseXxx` at runtime)

Comment: never touched the MongoDB, but int `BrandReputation = Integer.parseInt((String)obj.get("Brand Reputation"));` looks like as very supid and contraproductive in the case that there is stored integer `"Brand Reputation" : 7`, AFAIK almost of all of JDBC can take data_types corectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data gets added to an Object Array, you j\Just treat everything as an Object:

```
Object serialNumber = obj.get("SrNo");
Object brand = obj.get("Brand");
Object productName = obj.get("Product Name");
Object price = obj.get("Price");

model.addRow( new Object[] {serialNumber, brand, productName, price} );
```

Now the trick is to tell the TableModel what the data types are for each column so you need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the TableModel.

Some generic code would be:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0)
{
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
        {
            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

            if (o != null)
            {
                return o.getClass();
            }
        }

        return Object.class;
    }
};
```

Or you can be more specific:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0)
{
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        switch (column)
        {
            case 3: return Double.class;
            default: return String.class;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @cammickr   Will you please tell me what does the case number in the switch case statement represent?

Comment: @MikhilDesai, A JTable is used to display data in rows and columns. The method name is "getColumnClass(...)" and the parameter name is "column". So this method is used to tell the table what type of data is contained in a given "column" so the table can use an appropriate renderer.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly ... @camickr you nailed it!!